# Broadleaf 3.0.13 version deploy on tomcat with Solr server

Tags: tomcat, solr, broadleaf-commerce

No errors or specific warning in log.How to check in tomcat standalone server.

I am running Solr server and Demosite.war on same tomcat,below is the log on catalina.out file.

How can I check whether demosite.war is running or not,but it has been deployed as shown in log.

```
INFO: Initialization processed in 388 ms
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
0 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter – SolrDispatchFilter.init()
11 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader – Using JNDI solr.home: /home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore
12 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/'
125 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr – Loading container configuration from /home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/solr.xml
207 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer – New CoreContainer 711347551
208 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer – Loading cores into CoreContainer [instanceDir=/home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/]
220 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting socketTimeout to: 0
221 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting urlScheme to:
224 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting connTimeout to: 0
225 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20
225 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting corePoolSize to: 0
225 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647
225 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting maxThreadIdleTime to: 5
225 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting sizeOfQueue to: -1
225 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory – Setting fairnessPolicy to: false
372 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher – SLF4J impl is org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
373 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher – Registering Log Listener [Log4j (org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory)]
374 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer – Host Name:
415 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer – Creating SolrCore 'core1' using instanceDir: /home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1
415 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/'
467 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig – Using Lucene MatchVersion: LUCENE_40
552 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.Config – Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
557 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema – Reading Solr Schema from schema.xml
567 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema – [core1] Schema name=example
642 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema – unique key field: id
659 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – solr.StandardDirectoryFactory
665 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – [core1] Opening new SolrCore at /home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/, dataDir=/home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/data/
665 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – JMX monitoring not detected for core: core1
670 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – [core1] Added SolrEventListener for newSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener{}
670 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – [core1] Added SolrEventListener for firstSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener{queries=[{q=static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml}]}
682 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory – return new directory for /home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/data
682 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – New index directory detected: old=null new=/home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/data/index/
683 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory – return new directory for /home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/data/index
690 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – created json: solr.JSONResponseWriter
754 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – no updateRequestProcessorChain defined as default, creating implicit default
761 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – created /select: solr.SearchHandler
762 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – created /get: solr.RealTimeGetHandler
765 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – created /update: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
765 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.CSVRequestHandler
765 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – created /update/csv: solr.CSVRequestHandler
766 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler
766 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers – created /update/json: solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler
778 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
789 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – Hard AutoCommit: disabled
789 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – Soft AutoCommit: disabled
834 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits: num=1
commit{dir=/home/prasanna/solr4.7/example/multicore/core1/data/index,segFN=segments_4qp,generation=6145}
835 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – newest commit generation = 6145
885 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher – Opening Searcher@25c30f7e[core1] main
895 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer – registering core: core1
895 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@25c30f7e[core1] main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_4qp:17314:nrt _4qn(4.7):C36)}
897 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter – user.dir=/var/lib/tomcat7
897 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter – SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo.war
967 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – [core1] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+in+solrconfig.xml&distrib=false} hits=0 status=0 QTime=70
968 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – QuerySenderListener done.
968 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore – [core1] Registered new searcher Searcher@25c30f7e[core1] main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_4qp:17314:nrt _4qn(4.7):C36)}
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[SUPPORT] 21:27:10 DirectCopyClassTransformer(Offer Audit Fix) - Offer Audit Fix - START - Transform - Copying into [org.broadleafcommerce.core.offer.domain.OfferAuditImpl] from [org.broadleafcommerce.core.offer.domain.OfferAuditWeaveImpl]
[SUPPORT] 21:27:10 DirectCopyClassTransformer(Offer Audit Fix) - Offer Audit Fix - END - Transform - Copying into [org.broadleafcommerce.core.offer.domain.OfferAuditImpl] from [org.broadleafcommerce.core.offer.domain.OfferAuditWeaveImpl]
[ WARN] 21:27:12 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
[ WARN] 21:27:12 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
[ WARN] 21:27:13 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [blSandBoxElements]; using defaults.
[ WARN] 21:27:16 PassthroughEncryptionModule - This passthrough encryption module provides NO ENCRYPTION and should NOT be used in production.
[ WARN] 21:27:17 PassthroughEncryptionModule - This passthrough encryption module provides NO ENCRYPTION and should NOT be used in production.
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8983"]
23 Jan, 2015 9:27:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 20028 ms
```

Any helps that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks like it is starting up.

First you can see that solr is deployed
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml

The path to solr will be either /solr (as derived by the filename) or it may be defined in solr.xml

Then the demo app is deployed
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo.war

This app will be at /demo based on the demo.war filename

And finally, tomcat starts listening for incoming HTTP requests
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8983"]

so, in this example, assuming you launched tomcat on your local machine, you would open a browser and go to

http://localhost:8983/demo